# Delete Duplicate Rows in Django DB

Tags: python, django

I have a model where because of a code bug, there are duplicate rows. I now need to delete any duplicates from the database.

Every row should have a unique photo_id. Is there a simple way to remove them? Or do I need to do something like this:

```
rows = MyModel.objects.all()
for row in rows:
    try:
        MyModel.objects.get(photo_id=row.photo_id)
    except:
        row.delete()
```

Comment: It would be better, going forward, to define that field as unique in your database schema. Then you eliminate this problem from ever occuring. In fact, you should add such details to all of your database schema.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The simplest way is the simplest way! Especially for one off scripts where performance doesn't even matter (unless it does). Since it's not core code, I'd just write the first thing that comes to mind and *works*.

```
# assuming which duplicate is removed doesn't matter...
for row in MyModel.objects.all().reverse():
    if MyModel.objects.filter(photo_id=row.photo_id).count() > 1:
        row.delete()
```

Use `.reverse()` to delete the duplicates first and keep the first instance of it, rather than the last.

**As always, back up before you do this stuff.**

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a query that would just show me what rows are dups?  I know distinct will show me the db without dups, but what will show me just dups?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY photo_id HAVING COUNT(photo_id) > 1;`

Comment: @brenden, instead of deleting the rows, you could append them to a list? I removed my second query because I forgot that would match both duplicates and non duplicates... close one!

Comment: Yes going to add them to a list. But wondering how to get just the ones that are dups with a Django Query (instead of raw sql)

Comment: @Brenden: my 2 cents, it's not possible with django. It looks simliar to the infamous `Top N Group By` problem but worse because we'd need to select all but 1 of a varying number of duplicates. I think the closest we'll get to optimizing without SQL is using a 2 part query: `MyModel.objects.values('photo_id').order_by().annotate(c=Count('photo_id')).filter(c__gt=1)` will get you all duplicates by `photo_id` which you could iterate over and ensure you delete all but 1 per photo_id. I'd love to be wrong though... this could go in my toolbox!

Comment: this is going to be very slow for any kind of large table i think ... so an important caveat is that time does not matter

Comment: You forgot to include an import statement

Answer (score 25):

This may be faster because it avoids the inner filter for each row in MyModel.

Since the ids are unique, if the models are sorted by them in increasing order, we can keep track of the last id we saw and as we walk over the rows if we see a model with the same id, it must be a duplicate, so we can delete it.

```
lastSeenId = float('-Inf')
rows = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('photo_id')

for row in rows:
  if row.photo_id == lastSeenId:
    row.delete() # We've seen this id in a previous row
  else: # New id found, save it and check future rows for duplicates.
    lastSeenId = row.photo_id
```

Comment: Concerning performance, that's certainly the better choice! Thanks, we needed this for a large database!

Comment: Works well for converting a table to have a `unique_together` constraint as well, thanks!

Comment: Another nice feature is that it allows you to order by another field to keep the ones you want to keep at the top of the groups of dupes!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fast solution:

```py
from django.db import connection

query = "SELECT id FROM table_name GROUP BY unique_column HAVING COUNT(unique_column)>1"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
ids_list = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
```

now you can do:

```
Some_Model.objects.filter(id__in=ids_list).delete()
```

or if `ids_list` was too huge to be handled by your dbms

you can segment it to chunks that can be handled by it:

```py
seg_length = 100
ids_lists = [ids_list[x:x+seg_length] for x in range(0,len(ids_list),seg_length)]
for ids_list in ids_lists:
    SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids_list).delete()
```

Comment: This will delete only 1 of the duplicates. So you'd have to do this recursively if there were more than 2 of any rows. So it may not be faster than the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but if you really need performance and your table has +500k rows, this might help:

```py
last_used_id = 0
your_ids = list(MyModel.objects
                .order_by("your_id")
                .values_list('your_id',flat=True)
                .annotate(name_count=Count('your_id'))
                .filter(name_count__gt=1)[:1000] # for example
               )
duplicates = MyModel.objects
               .filter(your_id__in=your_ids)
               .order_by("your_id")

for my_model in duplicates:
  if my_model.your_id == last_used_id:
    my_model.delete()
  else:
    last_used_id = my_model.your_id
```

Answer (score 1):

from Django 1.11, you can use

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    count=Subquery(
        MyModel.objects.filter(
            photo_id=OuterRef('photo_id')
        ).values(
            'photo_id'
        ).annotate(
            count=Count('pk')
        ).values('count')
    )
).filter(
    count__gt=1
)
```

This query will give you the rows that don't have a unique photo_id, you can then  keep one row of each photo id and delete the rest

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating the whole table you can just do

```
count = MyModel.objects.filter(photo_id='some_photo_id').count()
while count >=1:
    MyModel.objects.filter(photo_id='some_photo_id')[0].delete()
    count -= 1
```

Comment: And how do you get those photo ids?  You'll still need to iterate through, naively, each id.  You can craft a solution that only iterates through duplicates, but it all hinges on how you get your list of ids.

Answer (score 0):

A general and optimized method in case large number of objects need to be deleted -

```
qs = Model.objects.all()
key_set = set()
delete_ids_list = []
for object in qs:
    object_key = object.unique_key    # photo_id here
    if object_key in key_set:
        delete_ids_list.append(object.id)
    else:
        key_set.add(object_key)
Model.objects.filter(id__in=delete_ids_list).delete()
```

Comment: What exactly leads you to believe this is optimized for large querysets? you aren't even using iterator...

Answer (score 0):

Combining some of the other answers along with a [Window](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) function allows you to annotate the row number. It's important to use a partition otherwise the row numbers will just be sequential. Iterate through the queryset and add any object where the row number is not the first occurrence to a list of ids that can be later deleted in one query.

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, IntegerField, OuterRef, Subquery, Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber

from group.models import BuyingGroupTemplate

templates = (
    BuyingGroupTemplate.objects
    .order_by('group', 'product')
    .annotate(
        count=Subquery(
            BuyingGroupTemplate.objects
            .filter(
                group=OuterRef('group'),
                product=OuterRef('product'),
            )
            .values('group', 'product')
            .annotate(count=Count('*'))
            .values('count'),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
        ),
        row_number=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by=[F('group'), F('product')],
            order_by=F('id').asc()
        ),
    )
    .filter(count__gt=1)
)
ids_to_delete = list()
for template in templates:
    if template.row_number != 1:
        ids_to_delete.append(template.id)

BuyingGroupTemplate.objects.filter(id__in=ids_to_delete).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of records, efficient way:

```
import itertools

pks_to_delete = []
rows = MyModel.objects.values_list('pk', 'photo_id').order_by('photo_id')
filter_func = lambda x: x[1]
for key, group in itertools.groupby(rows.iterator(), filter_func):
    pks_to_delete.extend((i[0] for i in list(group)[1:]))

MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=pks_to_delete).delete()
```