# How to delete duplicate rows from a table using Django ORM?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, duplicates

I have a database table `bad_reviews` and a corresponding Django model `BadReviews`. I want to delete duplicate records based on the fields `client_id`, `survey_id`, `text`, `rating`, `privacy_agreement`. I've come up with this query which works:

```
SELECT br.*
FROM bad_reviews br
JOIN (
    SELECT client_id, survey_id, text, rating, privacy_agreement, COUNT(*)
    FROM bad_reviews
    GROUP BY client_id, survey_id, text, rating, privacy_agreement
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) dupes
ON br.client_id = dupes.client_id
AND br.survey_id = dupes.survey_id
AND br.text = dupes.text
AND br.rating = dupes.rating
AND br.privacy_agreement = dupes.privacy_agreement
ORDER BY br.client_id, br.survey_id, br.text, br.rating, br.privacy_agreement, br.id
```

How to rewrite it using Django ORM?

Comment: If you run it only one time (as you are deleting), why not run this query in DB directly and delete stuff? ([How to run raw query in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw)) Because implementing it in ORM could be complicated, and simplest way of deleting in ORM is using brute force delete like showed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8965461/2696165

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work.

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Subquery


#  Equivalent of this query in with Django ORM: SELECT client_id, survey_id, text, rating, privacy_agreement, COUNT(*)
#     FROM bad_reviews
#     GROUP BY client_id, survey_id, text, rating, privacy_agreement
#     HAVING count(*) > 1
subquery = BadReviews.objects \
        .values('client_id', 'survey_id', 'text', 'rating', 'privacy_agreement') \
        .annotate(count=Count('id')).filter(count__gt=1)

# use the subquery as a filter in the main query
bad_reviews = BadReviews.objects.filter(
    client_id=Subquery(subquery.values('client_id')),
    survey_id=Subquery(subquery.values('survey_id')),
    text=Subquery(subquery.values('text')),
    rating=Subquery(subquery.values('rating')),
    privacy_agreement=Subquery(subquery.values('privacy_agreement')),
).order_by('client_id', 'survey_id', 'text', 'rating', 'privacy_agreement', 'id')
```